# Routing a location that matches one controller to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Hi I have a controller named "places" with some actions like "view", "new", "create"

When a user goes to mysite.com/places I want to execute the action "show" of another controller called "cores"

So I've put this in the routes.rb file:

```
map.connect '/places', :controller => "cores", :action => "show"
```

But it doesn't work.

I receive this error:

```
Processing PlacesController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-16 00:52:07) [GET]

ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to show. Actions: admin_denied, admin_required, auto_complete_for_location, auto_complete_for_name, change_location, create, create_facebook_session, create_facebook_session_with_secret, edit, exist, facebook_params, facebook_session, facebook_session_expired, facebook_session_parameters, get_form, is_admin?, new, one_or_true, redirect_to, render_publisher_error, render_publisher_interface, render_publisher_response, set_facebook_session, top_redirect_to, update, wants_interface?, and zero_or_false):
```

How do I map that action to another controller?

thanks

Comment: The URL `/places` does not match your route for `/:id/show`. What are you expecting the ID to be since you're not passing it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend getting more specific with your route, or else rethink the controller naming scheme.

Try this:

```
map.connect 'places', :controller => 'cores', :action => 'show'
```

URLs that match `places/:action/:id` will still continue to work.